# pig FILTER ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hortonworks-sandbox

This script working fine

```
data1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/test/u3.data' AS (usesrID:int, movieID:int, rating:int, ratingTime:int);
DUMP data1;
```

and the output is
[image]

When i used FILTER then PIG through error

```
data1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/test/u3.data' AS (usesrID:int, movieID:int, rating:int, ratingTime:int);
filterRowData1=filter data1 by (int)movieID == 556;
DUMP filterRowData1;
```

Error screen-shot
[image]
Error Detail:

> 2018-10-20 23:20:24,653 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Encountered "  "filterRowData1=filter "" at line 2, column 1.

I have also tried

```
data1 = LOAD '/user/maria_dev/ml-100k/test/u3.data' AS (usesrID:int, movieID:int, rating:int, ratingTime:int);
filterRowData1=filter data1 by movieID == 556; (i have tried: '556'; but no luck)
DUMP filterRowData1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
filterRowData1 = filter data1 by movieID == 556;
```

you should space between alias name and query.